# Paypal Pro (Payflow edition) API questions

Tags: paypal, payflowpro

I'm looking into paypal APIs (god there is a lot of them!)

My question is this:
There seem to be two editions for website payments pro (direct and payflow edition). See link below for the two guides:
https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-integration-guides#wpp

After talking with paypal, it seems they have switched over recently and are creating new pro accounts into the payflow edition while the old accounts are still direct payment edition. There is a new authentication scheme for the new payflow edition API.

1) Does anybody know if the two API's are completely different? They are both called website payments pro, but i have no idea about the APIs themselves.

2) Do both of them allow transparent redirect if they are different.

3) For express checkout, are the API calls different if i use express checkout api directly, vs with the pro (direct or payflow editions).

Thanks for alleviating my confusion. :)

Answer (score 2):

1)Payments Pro-PayFlow edition is same as Payments Pro Standard with one extra feature: recurring billing.

2) Paypal standard doesn't, pro does.

3) Express checkout works only with paypal accounts and is the easiest to implement. However it mandates that buyers have a paypal account.

Paypal Standard redirects users from your website to paypal.  Users need not have a paypal account to purchase stuff.  Users can choose to pay by logging into their paypal account or by credit/debit card.

Payments pro, keeps your users on your website throughout the payment processing period.

Check [this](http://www.zen-cart.com/content.php?70-whats-the-difference-between-paypal-standard-express-and-pro) for a detailed explanation of all these APIs.

Comment: Thanks, for 1, are they the same API with the one additional feature, or are they a different API set?  I ask b/c I would have to implement 2 API's potentially.  Also, from what i understand, pro-payflow edition let's you also choose your merchant processor so it doesn't have to be PayPal. Also, payflow in general doesn't work in the developer sandbox and i assume it is the same for the pro-payflow edition. for 3, i understand the purpose of express checkout vs. Pro, but my question is more about the API itself. The payflow docs have account specific calls to express checkout API.

Comment: 1) The implementation for both would be the same, yet they are different APIs.  Payments Pro-Payflow is the superset of the Paypal API.  The question you need to ask yourself is, if you need recurring payments?  If yes, use payflow else use standard.  

2) Paypal comes with a free merchant account.  If you want a separate processor, you'll have to pay a monthly fee for that.  So again, it's better to use paypal's free merchant account.  

3) Paypal recommends implementing express checkout if you use payments pro.

Comment: Whether you implement payments pro or not, express checkout calls are always account specific.  It's like you as a seller giv paypal your account info + the amount buyer owes you and when the buyer signs in with paypal and authorizes payment, paypal will just transfer whatever money buyer owes you to your account.  That's the reason why express checkout calls are account specific.